# Horizontal news banner?

Tags: sharepoint-online

Is it possible to have a rotating news banner that is managed from a list and displayed like this?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I hope you understand your question can be answered as "Yes".

Comment: would be nice to have some assistance :/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but you need to do some custom coding:

1. Find suitable JavaScript banner implementation/library from the net, that hopefully already supports UI you need
2. Use SharePoint CSOM (via JavaScript) to query list items
3. Output them in the HTML format banner library requires
4. Call the initialize function (or similar) of the banner library

You can put all code in a Script Editor web part, but for better developer experience, perhaps put them into a /_catalogs/masterpage/banner/banner.js file, and reference that from Content Editor Web Part. Then you can use Chrome SP Editor extension or even SharePoint Designer to work with the file.